# Removing Stopwords in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, stop-words

I'm trying to remove the stopwords from a user input string using the `.join` function. It looks like this:

```
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if line.strip() == stopword:
        break
    remove_stopwords = ''.join(word for word in line.split() if word not in stop_words)
```

I've defined `stop_words` in a list at the top. The problem is that when I type in the string for the stop words to be removed from, it only removes the first word and leaves the rest. Any help would be great. I'm new to this so it's probably something stupid.

Comment: where is `stopword` declared?

Comment: oh, that is also declared above the code shown. it is set to break when a line containing only a fullstop is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one liner using the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
" ".join(filter(lambda word: word not in stop_words, line.split()))
```

Additionally, consider storing your stop words in  a `set` rather than a `list`. The average algorithmic complexity of the search operation (`in`) is constant for a `set` and linear for a `list`.

Edit: Your program appears to be working as expected with an additional space for the `join` string. This makes sense as `(x for x in y if f(x))` is roughly equivalent to `filter`:

```
  stop_words = set(["hi", "bye"])
  stopword = "DONE"
  while True:
      line = raw_input()
      if line.strip() == stopword:
          break
      print(" ".join(word for word in line.split() if word not in stop_words))
```

input:

```
hello hi my name is bye justin
```

output:

```
hello my name is justin
```

Your bug must be somewhere else in your program. What else are you doing?

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Switching from the list to the set seemed to help the problem.